# Unable to build a solution which contains .Net Core and SQL projects

Tags: .net, msbuild, .net-core, dotnet-cli, sqlproj

One of my client have a solution which contains 4 dotnet core projects and 1 sql project in a single solution.
I tried to build the solution with dotnet core, but it is not able to find the sql project related target files and the build got failed.

I tried to add following arguments along with dotnet command but still not able to build the solution:

```
SQLDBExtensionsRefPath
VisualStudioVersion
MSBuildExtensionsPath
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to build this solution using only `msbuild.exe` of the VS 2017+ installation instead of `dotnet` commands.

e.g. instead of

```
dotnet build -c Release
```

you would need to call

```
msbuild -restore -p:Configuration=Release
```